# How to change gtk-entry icon size?

Tags: gtk

Is there any way to change the icon size of an gtk_entry / gtk_spin_button.
Because of using a touchscreen, i need much bigger icons.

I tried to change the gtkrc from my custom theme and added:

```
gtk-icon-sizes = "gtk-spin-button=48,48:gtk-entry=48,48"
```

Sadly this has no effect on my spin-button.
Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging through the gtk-source code just found the Answer, lucky me :)

I added

```
gtk-icon-sizes = "gtk-menu=48,48"
```

in the gtkrc of my theme and it's finally resizes my icons in gtk-entry and gtk-spin-button.